# How display a carousel only on the first page of the listing of product in each category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, list.phtml

Where you are in a category you have the list of your products.
I display actually a carousel a the position of a product.
But my problem i don't know how display only this carousel on the first and not on all the pages ?

Comment: please put relevnt code otherwise question goes to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way this could work is by getting the URL path of the pages you want the carousel to appear and running the code on these pages. You can do this well by following the answer in this thread. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192212/get-current-url-in-magento-and-show-something`

Try the code in second answer of this thread

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963557/how-to-display-category-description-only-on-the-first-page-in-magento
```

Comment: I already have tried with that method :  `<?php if ($this->getChild('favorite_carousel')->getToolbarBlock()->isFirstPage()) : ?>`
But i don't know why it's not working...

I tried with your method but it's not effective too

Comment: Not sure where the problem is but i will post a link to another thread where you can retrieve the 'p' variable of page and run code against that